# Dynamically filter ng-repeat on ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, filter

I'm building an app at http://creditcardairlinepoints.com and I want the user to be able to filter an array of credit cards by clicking a filter on the side of the interface e.g. only Amex cards, cards with no fee.

I'm able to bind the filter function to the user clicking the filter, but the function itself doesn't work as planned. There are two problems:

1. I can't seem to get the filter to default to null. One of the links is to display 'all cards' which works on click, by setting the filter to null but I can't get this to on page load.
2. I need to dynamically generate the filter e.g. cardFee:0, minSpend:0, bonusCurrency:amex and I'm not able to do this.

I'm wondering if I'm going about this the wrong way and rather than generate the filter based on variables passed in from the array via the front end I should setup a loop e.g.

- if filterId = 0, do nothing
- if filterId = 1, show amex cards

**Filter list**

The list of filter links generated from an array using ng-repeat. I've bound this successfully to the function below and can successfully pass values to it.

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li ng-repeat="filter in filters" 
        ng-click="selectFilter($index);setFilter(filter.property, filter.value)" 
        ng-class="{active: $index===selectedIndex}">
        <a href="#">{{ filter.anchor }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Card Output**

Cards output to table cells in a given row, this is what I'd like to filter on click.

```
<tr ng-repeat="card in cards | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:cardFilter">
```

**Filter array**

The card array works fine and if I code up any of these filters statically it works.

```
$scope.filters = [
    {
        'filterId': 0,
        'anchor': 'All cards',
        'property': '',
        'value': ''
    },
    {
        'filterId': 1,
        'anchor': 'American Express cards',
        'property': 'bonusCurrency',
        'value': 'amex'
    },
    {
        'filterId': 2,
        'anchor': 'Avios cards',
        'property': 'bonusCurrency',
        'value': 'avios'
    },
    {
        'filterId': 3,
        'anchor': 'No fee',
        'property': 'cardFee',
        'value': '0'
    },
    {
        'filterId': 4,
        'anchor': 'No minimum spend',
        'property': 'minSpend',
        'value': '0'
    }
];
```

**Filter function**

What I'm trying to achieve, a dynamically generated filter with a null default.

```
/* Set first filter link to default */
$scope.cardFilter = ''; 

$scope.setFilter = function ( k, v ) {
    $scope.cardFilter = {k:v};
};
```

Comment: If you can add fiddle, than we can help you in better way..

Comment: Bad design. Using filters is not proper way. The best solution is to make a function which adjusts the data for ng-repeat after changing the filtering parameters.

Comment: So on click, take the original array, filter it and then spit out the updated version?

Answer (score 1):

Got this working in the end by approaching the problem in a different way. I assigned each card object in the array a property 'status' of 1 by default. If the status value === 1, then it is shown in the DOM.

When a user clicks a filter, the ID of the link they've clicked is sent through to app.js which then updates the status property of all cards in the array, dependent on a small piece of logic associated with each link.

ng-if then iterates through the array and hides/shows elements dependent on their updated status.

**Filter Links**

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li ng-repeat="filter in filters" ng-click="selectFilter($index);updateStatus(filter.filterId)" ng-class="{active: $index===selectedIndex}"><a href="#"></span>{{ filter.anchor }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Table output**

```
<tr ng-repeat="card in cards | orderBy:predicate:reverse" ng-if="cardFilter(card.cardStatus)">
```

**Sample Card Object from cards array**

```
{
        cardName: "American Express Preferred Rewards Gold",
        cardStatus: 1,
        cardBonus: 10000,
        cardBonusVisual: 10000,
        bonusValue: 100,
        bonusCurrency: "spg",
        bonusCurrencyVisual: "SPG points",
        cardFeeSymbol: "£",
        minSpendSymbol: "£",
        cardFee: 75,
        cardFeeVisual: "75",
        imageName: "spg.jpg", 
        minSpend: 1000,
        minSpendVisual: "1000",
        spendTimeLimit: 90,
        spendTimeLimitVisual: "90",
        spendTimeLimitDays: "days",
        cardURL: "https://www252.americanexpress.com/inga/uk/pers/begin.do?perform=IntlEapp:UK:triCredit&journey=B&intlink=uk-amex-cardshop-britishairwaysamericanexpresscreditcard-detail-applynow-main"
    }
```

**Filters Array**

```
$scope.filters = [
    {
        'filterId': 0,
        'anchor': 'All cards'
    },
    {
        'filterId': 1,
        'anchor': 'American Express cards'
    },
    {
        'filterId': 2,
        'anchor': 'Avios cards'
    },
    {
        'filterId': 3,
        'anchor': 'No fee'
    },
    {
        'filterId': 4,
        'anchor': 'No minimum spend'
    }
];
```

**Function to hide/show cards in table**

```
$scope.cardFilter = function(cardStatus){
    if(cardStatus === 1){
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```